# How to shorten table entrees for duplications

Tags: apache-spark, join, union

I have a source dataset of 200k records. I have two columns, I want to count distinct values for:

I have this:

```
val scr1 = spark.read.parquet("src1.parquet")
val dAppr = bp.groupBy("approver").count().toDF("name","Role1")
val cols1 = dAppr.columns.toSet

val dRevr = bp.groupBy("submitter").count().toDF("name","Role2")
val cols2 = dRevr.columns.toSet

val Signers1 = cols1 ++ cols2

def expr(myCols: Set[String], allCols: Set[String]) = {
  allCols.toList.map(x => x match {
    case x if myCols.contains(x) => col(x)
    case _ => lit(null).as(x)
  })
}

dAppr.select(expr(cols1, Signers1):_*).unionAll(dRevr.select(expr(cols2, Signers1):_*)).show()
```

I get:

```
+--------+---------+----------+
|    name|    Role1|     Role2|
+--------+---------+----------+
|Person A|    19421|      null|
|Person B|    41993|      null|
|Person C|    58822|      null|
|Person D|    48920|      null|
|Person A|     null|     53615|
|Person B|     null|     55904|
|Person C|     null|       118|
|Person D|     null|     59519|
+--------+---------+----------+
```

I want (or, I THINK I want):

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|    name|    Role1|    Role2|
+--------+---------+---------+
|Person A|    19421|    53615|
|Person B|    41993|    55904|
|Person C|    58822|      118|
|Person D|    48920|    59519|
+--------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `join` instead of `union` in the last line of code.

Look like you can use `full join` on `name` column

join

`Joins with another :class:DataFrame, using the given join expression`

union

`Return a new :class:DataFrame containing union of rows in this and another frame`

**edit:**

you can remove those lines:

```
def expr(myCols: Set[String], allCols: Set[String]) = {
  allCols.toList.map(x => x match {
    case x if myCols.contains(x) => col(x)
    case _ => lit(null).as(x)
  })
}

dAppr.select(expr(cols1, Signers1):_*).unionAll(dRevr.select(expr(cols2, Signers1):_*)).show()
```

and use full join with select on the relevant columns.